# XPages - how to assign OneUI3 theme?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, ibm-oneui

I have a new XPages app with Domino 9 but I don't see an option to have OneUI3 there. I got also the XPages Demo App 2.0 from OpenNTF where this option exists, however I could not find where does it come from. If I just copy the demo app xsp.properties source code to my application, it does not work. Do I have to do something special with my application to get this theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no predefined choice or option for that.
Just edit the source of your XSP properties file OR create and use a theme. Extend the theme from the "oneuiv3.0.2" theme to get this working. Details here: http://mardou.dyndns.org/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=96AB51B29A4F4369C1257B1D0064D05F

Comment: As I said, I tried to set xsp.theme=oneuiv3.0.2 as in the XPages Demo app but it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm strange. Did you try it using a custom theme extending that "oneuiv3.0.2" thing?

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I saw a thin line instead of the banner and thought it does not work. Indeed it works, just for OneUI2.1 the banner is always shown even if there's no logo or links but for OneUI3 the black bar is only shown if there's something to show, if not it just shows the thin blue line.

The only thing I find strange is the banner height. In the OneUI documentation and in Connections it is definitely more narrow than in the XPages extlib.

Comment: I edited my article above and added some CSS to redesign the banner height and stuff.

Comment: OK, so where are the onuiv3.0.2.theme and related files? They are not in the <xserver>\xsp\nsf\themes directory.

Comment: I guess files are built in to the extension library that is shipped with Notes/Domino 9